# Simulate a (Ctrl ) + (-) zoom out event using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do we simulate a Ctrl - zoom out using Javascript? The style zoom property or the transform property seems to zoom out but differently with white space in the corners and not like how your typical Ctrl - zoom out on your browser would look like.

Through Javascript I tried the KeyboardEvent but it does not do the trick

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {key:"-", code:45 ,ctrlKey:true});
document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to emulate the browser zoom itself as opposed to just zooming in on the elements?

Comment: Yes that's because I want my page to be atleast 1920px wide with occupying the entire width of the browser and that seems to be only possible when you zoom out using browser in low resolution screens

Comment: Are you trying to substitute responsiveness with emulating a zoom? Because I would definitely advise against that, but let me answer your question here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're set on using Javascript, so I'll leave a CSS option for you here as well. CSS has an accessibility feature appropriately called [Zoom](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/) which will do what you're asking.

```
div {
  zoom: 200%
}
```

As far as actually emulating the button press, though, try this;

```
  var event = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  event.which = 107;       // Key code for +
  event.ctrlkey = true;     
  $(document).trigger(event);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom + triggering a keydown event doesn't emulate actual key strokes, it just executes the keydown listener(s) if attached.

Comment: Yup it does...is there a way to emulate actual key strokes?

Answer (score 0):

You are mis-using the key attribute. Use e.g. this instead:

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Minus' });
```

Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) to the list of values for `KeyboardEvent.key`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h1>Result</h1>
        <button>Trigger Ctrl and - Keypress</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        let btn = document.querySelector("button");
        let result = document.querySelector("h1");

        // Normally keyboard pressed event
        document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
            if (e.keyCode == 189 && e.ctrlKey) {
                result.innerText = "Ctrl Key and - key Pressed";
                ps();
            }
        });

        // Button event
        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            const keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
                ctrlKey: true,
                keyCode: 189
            });
            document.body.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
            ps();
        });

        const ps = () => {
            // back to previous state
            setTimeout(() => {
                result.innerHTML = "Result";
            }, 2000);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.